# My LibGdx 1.1.0 not working?

Tags: libgdx

I Recently downloaded 1.1.0 version of `libgdx` that was near about 54 MB.

When I run `gdx-setup.jar` it again downloads from gradle.

When my Internet is disconnected if fails, why?

How to use downloaded files? Do I need to download every-time I create a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `gdx-setup-jar` is programmed to download libgdx each time you create a project, and does not search your computer for libgdx and I do not believe there is an easy way to get past that. You can import your project into your IDE once you have set it up with the gradle plugin. Here are some links that should help you install the gradle plugin.

[Eclipse Gradle](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Eclipse)

[Intellij IDEA Gradle](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA)

[NetBeans Gradle](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-NetBeans)

[Installing Gradle With the Commandline](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline)

I hope this answer was helpful :)

Comment: That means it will download every time i create a project.version 0.9.8 does it support physics box2d? i know there is an extension in version 1.1.0 but how to include this to version 0.9.8

Comment: You may not have the most recent version of the `libgdx-setup-jar`. By default it creates a project v1.0.1 and you can choose to inclue box2D.